# What algorithm can I use to sort tags for tag cloud?

Tags: java, tag-cloud, bucket

So I am creating a tag cloud containing X amount of tags. Something like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Web_2.0_Map.svg
The more often a keyword is used the bigger then font size it will have. For my tag cloud, I have X amount of tags which I will need to group by font size. I have a structure called a FacetBucket which contains the tag and its frequency. Most commonly used phrases will have the largest font size and least frequently used terms will have the smallest font size. The moderately used terms will all have font sizes between the largest and smallest. SO my problem is that I have X amount of tags and Y amount of font sizes, what kind of algorithm should I be looking for to solve my problem?

Comment: Why do you think that you will have an equal amount of tags and sizes (you used `X` for both)? Your font size selection is limited while user fantasy is not.

Comment: Sorry, X amount of tags and Y amount of font sizes

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking to do something simillar heres an equation that helps.

```
We will use the following variables, namely:
a = the smallest count (or occurrence).
b = the count of the tag being computed.
c = the largest count.
w = the smallest font-size.
x = the font-size for the tag. It is the unknown.
y = the largest font-size.


Now let's substitute the given values to their respective variables. Assuming that we are solving for the "thanksgiving" font-size.
a = 88
b = 168
c = 211
w = 12
x = ?
y = 50

And here's the formula:


x =   (b-a) (y-w)
    ----------- + w
      (c-a)


Or to put it in one liner (using c-like syntax):


x =  ( ((b-a) * (y-w)) / (c-a) ) + w
```

Taken from http://blog.16codes.com/2007/12/how-to-create-tag-cloud-with-formula.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to decide on the limited set of font sizes you intend to use (which depends on your GUI implementation).
2. Then you will assign each size to ranges of tag frequencies. Ranges will depend on `X` and `Y` values.

That will determine which font size each frequency get, with the understanding that close in value frequencies are to be displayed in the same size as long as number of tags exceeds the available amount of font sizes.

There is not much of algorithm actually needed.

Comment: The # of font sizes is determined by the user, as is the tag cloud. Obviously i will need error checking incase the user tries to use more font sizes then tags... But i want to to make this as dynamic as possible so an algorithm will be necessary.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested that you create **ranges** dynamically.  The number of font sizes is not determined by a user, but by user environment and mostly by your GUI implementation.  The basic algorithm is the same as dividing apples between groups of kids with the understanding that each kid might not get exactly the same portion but very close to that.